# Disable visibility of selection item in comboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a program consist of combo box:

[image]

Have the designer like:

```
        this.month_list.AllowDrop = true;
        this.month_list.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.month_list.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "JAN",
        "FEB",
        "MAR",
        "APR",
        "MAY",
        "JUN",
        "JUL",
        "AUG",
        "SEP",
        "OCT",
        "NOV",
        "DEC"});
        this.month_list.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 13);
        this.month_list.Name = "month_list";
        this.month_list.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 24);
        this.month_list.TabIndex = 13;
```

Now my question is it possible to disable the month selection visibility if month option is future or next to current month? Or in other words say now is march,so the user will not able to click APR,MAY and so-on. Any idea please advise.

Comment: Apply some logic to remove those months in `this.month_list`?

Comment: @Mr.SuicideSheep Is it possible to just disable the selection rather than remove?

Comment: The ComboBox will always display all its Items, so no, you can't "disable" them.

Comment: @LucMorin owh okay, so any idea how to solve this idea?

Comment: I take it you don't like my answer of simply not adding the "later" months to the ComboBox ?

Comment: There are ways, but not "out of the box". You would have to implement your own ComboBox derived class (to render the items in a different color if they are disabled), and some other logic to handle whether those items are enabled or disabled.

Comment: @LucMorin sorry but im new to this, can you please guide me more?

Comment: Are you talking about my solution, or do you still want to disable the items in the ComboBox ?

Comment: @LucMorin as you said the ComboBox will always display all its Items, and theres no way to "disable" it. So I thought theres no solution to disable the combobox rite?

Answer (score 2):

Add a handler on the year `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged`, and in it repopulate the month list based on the current date and year selected.

If year is 2014, then don't add the month greater than the current one to your month list.

EDIT:

```
private void yearCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(int.Parse(yearCombo.Text) > DateTime.Now.Year)
    {
        //remove all entries from ComboBox
    }
    else if (int.Parse(yearCombo.Text) == DateTime.Now.Year)
    {
        //Just add the months up to current month
    }
    else
    {
        //Add all months
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good idea,but can you guide me more please,im noob here and have no idea how to make this possible..

Comment: @Ren see my update. Please understand that I can't write the whole thing for you in only a few lines of code.

Comment: actually I do have, so how should it be?

Comment: @Ren updated to account for years > now, though I don't see why you'd have 2015 if you won't allow the user to select a month

Comment: I do this because it will easy to use in the future, theres no need to manually update and add the year.correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly to tell that disable item in combobox only supported in VS2003-2005.

You may only remove them via the below code (If you wish to remove the item from the existing combobox):

```
// To remove item with index 0:
this.month_list.Items.RemoveAt(0);
// To remove currently selected item:
this.month_list.Items.Remove(this.month_list.SelectedItem);
// To remove "JAN" item:
this.month_list.Items.Remove("JAN");
```

The below code is combining the idea of Luc Morin's answer jonathanh8686's answer which you may find it helpful:

First you make a dictionary as what jonathanh8686's answer stated:

```
Dictionary<int,string> months = new Dictionary<int,string>(); 
months.add(1, "Jan");
months.add(2, "Feb");
```

Then everytime when the user change the year Combobox, you reset the month combobox as below:

```
private void yearCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(int.Parse(yearCombo.Text) > DateTime.Now.Year)
    {
        //remove all entries from ComboBox
        this.month_list.Items.Clear();
    }
    else if (int.Parse(yearCombo.Text) == DateTime.Now.Year)
    {
        //Just add the months up to current month
        this.month_list.Items.Clear();
        int monthnumber = 1;

        while(monthnumber <= DateTime.Now.Month)
        {
            this.month_list.Items.Add(months[monthnumber]);
            monthnumber++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Add all months
        this.month_list.Items.Clear();
        int monthnumber = 1;

        while(monthnumber <= 12)
        {
            this.month_list.Items.Add(months[monthnumber]);
            monthnumber++;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie at C# so im not the best person to answer this but I have a idea about how to do this
I'm not sure about the exact code for this but heres a idea that could be used:

Make a datetime that contains the month

```
int month = 1;
int monthnumber = 1;
Datetime dt = new DateTime();
```

Then you could make a dictionary that has a key of the number month and key of the number of month so like:

```
Dictionary<int,string> months = new Dictionary<int,string>(); 
months.add(1, "Jan");
months.add(2, "Feb");
```

and so on...
after that do check for the month and look at the current month so if its March

```
if(dt.Month = March)
 {
     month = 3;
 }
```

so then after that
add all the months that are less than 3 like this:

```
while(monthnumber < months)
{
    this.month_list.Items.Add(dates.Value);
    monthnumber++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write custom code to draw the items of the combo box yourself.

Add these event handlers to the month list as well:

```
this.month_list.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
this.month_list.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.comboBox1_DrawItem);
this.month_list.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);


Font font = new Font("Aerial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
bool DisableIndex(int index)
    {
        return index > DateTime.Now.Month - 1;
    }
    private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Brush brushToDrawWith = DisableIndex(e.Index) ? Brushes.LightSlateGray : Brushes.Black;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.month_list.Items[e.Index].ToString(), font, brushToDrawWith, e.Bounds);
    }
    void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DisableIndex(month_list.SelectedIndex))
        {
            month_list.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }
```